# Initialize Array of Struct - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

If I have a variable called `Tree * myTree`, how could could I put this variable into an array of `Tree*`?

For example, I want to do something like:

```
Tree *allTrees[10];
allTrees = malloc(sizeof(Tree) * 10;
for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
{
    allTrees[i] = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
}
allTrees[0] = myTree;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @WhozCraig: And the question remains: what is the error? Specifically the compiler's error message should be included in the question. (I'm sure you know this; I'm prodding the OP.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I just realized its moot (the missing paren) regardless. Your comment in Byteventeurer's answer below is the real issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I hadn't even notice the missing `)` (*chuckle*)

Comment: If you're confused about arrays and pointers, read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do

```
allTrees = malloc(sizeof(Tree) * 10);
```

because you are already allocating the array on the stack:

```
Tree *allTrees[10];
```

The rest should be fine.

Comment: Not only don't you need to, you can't. `allTrees` is an array, and you can't assign to an array.